# How to link multiple columns to one on Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, relationship

I want to create a database where i simply need to type in the ID for something in multiple columns and this can bring me to when it was created and by who.[image]

As you can see the Power on, TV, HDMI etc have an ID that will go up to 12, with model C having overlap between some ID's from A and B

[image]
From this i can then determine that the ID 4 was created by Charlie

[image]
The problem i have is that i have linked the two together like this, but it does not work, i cannot see who made the command. Have i done this correctly and is it possible to do

Comment: Alternative is to normalize data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring in five more instances of `Relationship Table` which will, by default, be suffixed with `_1`, `_2`, etc.

Now, rearrange relations for the fields in table `Sony` to the individual `Relationship Table` tables.

Comment: When inside a form it still only reads the first instance of the IRid however and not the rest.

Comment: You may have follow the advice from @June7.